# Google chrome - playing a file from local storage is not working

Tags: javascript, windows, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I need to play video file in local Kiosk. Which has Windows 8.1 64-bit, with Google canary/chrome latest version. I have same problem with latest Google Chrome/canary versions its not playing files from local storage. If i play from cloud i have bandwidth issue+ there is no internet access for the kiosk.

Step 1 : allow everything zero restrictions

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Step 2:

Now i open a remote url https://stackoverflow.com/test.html, which is trying to play a video file which is located in the users PC, C:\loop.webm

example: test.html

```
<video id="mediaplayer" autoplay="autoplay" poster="/images/vlc.jpg" type="video/webm" loop="" src="file:///C:/loop.webm" style="display: inline;"></video>
```

Result:

```
The page at 'https://....mysite.com/test.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'file:///C:/loop.mp4': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Gives no error, but does not read a file, play the file at all.

How can i play the file in this case?

Comment: maybe chrome doesn't have perms to c:\ like you do, try a folder you know it can reach, like temp, or the chrome folder itself.

Comment: Did with temp folder too but same, it keep saying The page at 'https://....' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'file:///C:/...': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: This is not fare because look i told Chrome to allow those local access, even then he is not allowing me. e.g: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --incognito --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security

Comment: there might be a chrome switch that will allow this. There seem to be a couple related to security: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what's wrong!
The C:\ drive doesn't have a HTTPS certificate - it can't - but the website you are using has one. Chrome is doing this to protect a user's security. If you want to load a video file from the C:\ drive, you need to do it on a non-https website.

EDIT:
This plugin appears to be a work-around:
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida

Comment: I agree. But this is logicaly wrong and should be considered as BUG. Because you can see in command line argument i have explicitly mentioned  to allow me access, even the user accepting it. Why would still Google not allow this type of access? this makes a fatal use of Google in my kiosk case. For tihs issue i need to now change my whole application which is not fare at all.

Comment: Either way, why DO you need https?
Chrome is hard-coded to avoid security holes like this. YOu would have to recompile chrome to remove it. It's annoying, but it's a security feture that's hard-coded into chrome, and you'll have to work around it.

Comment: I must need HTTPS because i am offering cloud based services. People buy the cloud partitions, i cant give them my source code to run it locally.

Comment: How do i remove this featuer from hard-coded section do you have any idea about that, then i will recompile my own version which deny all those not logical security bridges.

Comment: I have found a plugin that appears to fix your issue. I'll edit the question, and please accept it if it works. Thanks!
https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida

Comment: OK - looking forwad. Please show step by step, so that i can test now and accept it.

Comment: Simply install that plugin, go to the plugin manager and allow it in incontigo mode, then the page you already have should work

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome/Canary do not support it even via command line if its applied. Temporary using Nginx to execute the files locally.